# All UIView Transition Animations Stop Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, calayer

I have an app who's main view that has 5 modal transitions (presentViewController) and one custom drop down animation ([UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^ { ...).

For some reason - potentially connected to updating to the new Xcode 7 beta - after a couple second ALL animations, including the iOS view transitions, stop animating for the entire app.

I'm aware that CALayer has it' own animation thread but I didn't think that it could be blocked.

I can't share code unfortunately, but does anyone have an idea of where to start looking?

I've looked at all the things I can find here and none of the answers seem to be about this particular type of issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does animation freeze or jumps to the end state instantly?

Comment: The transitions and the custom animation just jump to the end state.  No freeze.  So the app "works" but everyone misses the animation since it's jarring.

Comment: Have you tried this workaround ? `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]` . It seems like it would address your animation issues.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you're calling the UI from a thread other than Main.

Answer (score 0):

This one ended up actually being because there was some bad coding on the business logic that was, in fact, blocking the UI thread.
So 1up for Andres Canella.  The problem was the blocking of the main thread, only it was business logic blocking it in seemingly unrelated - and difficult to debug - ways.

NEVER BE AFRAID TO REBUILD "TAR BALL" LEGACY CODE!!!!!!!!!!

Also 1up for frakman1 because that's a good reminder.

Thanks all.